# UV will NOT unwrap

Tags: uv

So I've done UVunwrapping before on other projects, fine. Folling the same tutorials this time UV unwrapping will NOT work no matter how many times I try different ways marking seams, using follow quads, smart unwrap.. etc..

I've tried it on one version of the bottle with no subdivisions and no solidify added. Does NOT work. I've tried it on another version with those modifiers added. NOTHING works! Please help me!

Bottle with **NO modifiers** added: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/Templeton/TempletonBottle.blend

Bottle with **modifiers** added: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/Templeton/TempletonBottle2.blend

Comment: As I tried, everything unwraps just fine (as of 2.75). You select one of loops from top to bottom (that will be enough already to start with), mark as seam with  `Ctrl`+`E`, then select everything and unwrap. You will get stretch, of course, but you'll see the process going

Comment: 2.76, the no modifiers version unwraps just fine: edit mode, select all, U > smart UV project > OK without selecting any seam or else... keep in mind these are 2 objects: bottle + cap. same goes with modifiers.